# Can't go through administrator protection with python

Tags: python, administrator

I was making a script to have a better look on which folder take the most place by going through all the folders and adding their size but i have some administrator problems when it comes to a protected folder. How can i get through this?

```py
import os
import plotly.express as px

values = []
names = []
total = 0
ratio = []

def get_dir_size(pathall):
    dirlist = []
    with os.scandir(pathall) as maindir:
        for path in maindir:
            if path.is_dir():
                total = 0
                with os.scandir(path) as it:
                    for entry in it:
                        if entry.is_file():
                            total += entry.stat().st_size
                        elif entry.is_dir():
                            total += get_indir_size(entry.path)
                dirlist.append([path.name, total])
    return dirlist

def get_indir_size(path):
    total = 0
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
        for entry in it:
            if entry.is_file():
                total += entry.stat().st_size
            elif entry.is_dir():
                total += get_indir_size(entry.path)
    return total


folder = input('folder: \n>')
result = get_dir_size(folder)

for inst in result:
    values.append(inst[1])
    names.append(inst[0])

for value in values:
    total += value

for value in values:
    ratio.append(int(value/total*1000)/10)

print(result)
print(names, ratio)
pie = px.pie(values=ratio, names=names, width=1000, height=1000)
pie.show()
```

There is the output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programmation\folder analizer\__main__.py", line 36, in <module>
    result = get_dir_size(folder)
  File "E:\Programmation\folder analizer\__main__.py", line 20, in get_dir_size
    total += get_indir_size(entry.path)
  File "E:\Programmation\folder analizer\__main__.py", line 26, in get_indir_size
    with os.scandir(path) as it:
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acces Denied: 'C:\\Users\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
```

Comment: You'd have to run the script as an administrator or with administrator privileges. Python can't break through that (which is a good thing).

Comment: *"which is a good thing"*.  Too right! Imagine if someone needed to do to access and modify protected files on a Windows PC was to write (or download) and run a python script.  Hacker's paradise.

Comment: @sj95126 thanks for the answer but how can i do that?